# Use \newtheoremstyle to define a custom example environment

Tags: environments, theorems, amsthm, examples

I am trying to define a custom example environment for my thesis, but with my limited knowledge of LaTeX I am not able to figure this out from the [`amsthm` documentation](ftp://ftp.ams.org/pub/tex/doc/amscls/amsthdoc.pdf). Here is a minimum working example, or more correctly a working example of how I wished it looked like.

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{blindtext}

\usepackage{amsthm}
\newtheoremstyle{example} ... % something to add that makes sense

\begin{document}

\chapter{First Chapter}
\blindtext

\begin{example}
Here is an example with with some random text that covers multiple lines such that we have a good visual understanding of the lay-out. The example must cover about three lines.
\end{example}

\blindtext

\begin{example}
Here is another example with with some random text that covers multiple lines such that we have a good visual understanding of the lay-out. The example must cover about three lines.
\end{example}

And some text at the end of the chapter.

\end{document}
```

And then the output I would like to have, should look like:

[image]

I tried to use `\newtheoremstyle{break}` as it is described in the `amsthm` documentation on page 9, but I didn't succeed. Preferably I would also like to be able to set the space above and below the example such that it is clear where the example stops from the spacing in the lay-out. I hope this isn't a dumb question, but I simply couldn't figure it out myself from the documentation.

Best,
Koen

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's quite easy to do with `ntheorem`. I loaded the package with options `thref` (extended references for theorem-like environments) and `thmmarks` (automatic placement of end-of-proof symbols, including when the proof ends up in equations):

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{amsmath} %
\usepackage{blindtext}

\usepackage[thref, thmmarks, amsmath]{ntheorem}
\theoremstyle{break}
\theoremheaderfont{\bfseries}
\theorembodyfont{\normalfont}
\theoremseparator{\medskip}
\theorempreskip{\bigskipamount}
\newtheorem{example}{Example}[chapter]

\begin{document}

\chapter{First Chapter}

\blindtext

\begin{example}
  Here is an example with with some random text that covers multiple lines such that we have a good visual understanding of the lay-out. The example must cover about three lines.
\end{example}

\blindtext

\begin{example}
  Here is another example with with some random text that covers multiple lines such that we have a good visual understanding of the lay-out. The example must cover about three lines.
\end{example}

And some text at the end of the chapter.

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you Bernard, this does exactly what it supposed to do for me. The only problem for me was that it conflicted with theorem environments that I already defined with the `amsthm` package. But with the help of your solution I was able to understand the `amsthm`  documentation andI have came with a similar solution using this package. I will add it below for the interested reader.

Comment: I didn't mention it, but `ntheorem` has an `amsthm` option, which ensures compatibility with the default amsthm layouts. On the whole, I find ntheorem much easier to customise and it is better at end-of-proof placing.

Comment: Yes it should, but for some reason it didn't work for me. For now I am satisfied with the `amsthm`  package so I leave it with that for now, but I will definitely consider the `ntheorem` package for a next project.

Answer (score 2):

The answer from Bernard worked fine, but if you want to stick with the `amsthm` package then you can also do the following as I later found out.

```
    \documentclass{book}
    \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
    \usepackage[english]{babel}
    \usepackage{amsmath} %
    \usepackage{blindtext}

    \newtheoremstyle{break}%
    {2em}{2em}%
    {}{}%
    {\bfseries}{}% % Note that final punctuation is omitted.
    {\newline}{}

    \theoremstyle{break}
    \newtheorem{example}{Example}[chapter]

    \begin{document}

    \chapter{First Chapter}

    \blindtext

    \begin{example}
      Here is an example with with some random text that covers multiple lines such that we have a good visual understanding of the lay-out. The example must cover about three lines.
    \end{example}

    \blindtext

    \begin{example}
      Here is another example with with some random text that covers multiple lines such that we have a good visual understanding of the lay-out. The example must cover about three lines.
    \end{example}

    And some text at the end of the chapter.

    \end{document}
```

This gives a very similar output and with the part `{2em}{2em}` in the `\newtheoremstyle{break}` I was able to manually choose a whitespace above and below the new environment.